# Regexp match until next repeated occurance

Tags: regex, string, parsing

Parsing a log file. An entry starts with a date, then additional info is followed by tab characters. I got everything but the log details...

The log details can span many lines. So I need to capture all the text until the next log entry...

I've got it to the point where I only capture the first line of a log,
or I end up capturing every other entry (by putting a non-capturing date regexp at the end),
or it captures the whole file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex based on lookahead:

```
^([\d/ :.]+)\t\((\d+)\)\t(\[.+\])\t([\s\S]*?)\n?(?=^\d\d/|\z)
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW3zR1/9)

Comment: Sweet. That's precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: Misses last entry though... EOF character?

Comment: Yes I just spotted that. Check my updated regex and new demo link.

Comment: These parsing regexps take quite a bit of patience to build, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81, my job got little easier since OP posted one demo link of his attempted regex here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this global find:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}.*?(?=^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|\Z)
using flage: g m s
```

I edited it so it does not miss the last message.